# Sum mutiplies the result in my query

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm doing the query and is fine show all I want:

```
SELECT prog.cod_go, prog.data, prog.item, prog.tempoexposicao
FROM tb_programacao prog 
JOIN tb_go go ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go where go.cod_go = '1' 
AND go.equi_func1_mat = '0735'
AND prog.data = '2014-01-24' 
GROUP BY prog.data,prog.item

result:
cod_go | data      | item | tempoexposicao
1      |2014-01-24 | 10   | 00:00:30
1      |2014-01-24 | 11   | 00:00:30
1      |2014-01-24 | 12   | 00:00:30
1      |2014-01-24 | 13   | 00:00:30
1      |2014-01-24 | 14   | 00:00:30
1      |2014-01-24 | 8    | 00:00:30
1      |2014-01-24 | 9    | 00:00:30
```

and after that I tried the sum of all this "tempoexposicao" field like that

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(temp.soma))) AS soma_tudo, temp.cod_go, temp.data, temp.item 
FROM ( SELECT SUM( prog.tempoexposicao) AS 'soma', prog.cod_go, prog.data, prog.item 
FROM tb_programacao prog 
JOIN tb_go go ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go where go.cod_go = '1'
AND go.equi_func1_mat = '0735' 
AND prog.data = '2014-01-24' 
GROUP BY prog.data,prog.item ) AS temp

result:
soma_tudo | cod_go | data      | item
00:42:00  | 1      |2014-01-24 | 10
```

I expect 00:03:30 not 00:42:00, i can't do this subquery ?

Comment: the field type is Time

Comment: Why are you using `SUM` on the derived table?

Comment: i want to sum all the times after select them

Comment: Right, but you have SUM on the outer query and the inner query, so maybe it's giving 42:00 instead of 3:30 because it's taking the sum every time and if there are 12 rows, that would be 12 * 3:30, which is 42:00.  Change `SUM( prog.tempoexposicao) AS 'soma'` to just `prog.tempoexposicao AS 'soma'` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your base query:

```
SELECT prog.cod_go, prog.data, prog.item, prog.tempoexposicao
FROM tb_programacao prog JOIN
    tb_go go
    ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
where go.cod_go = '1' AND
     go.equi_func1_mat = '0735' AND
     prog.data = '2014-01-24' 
GROUP BY prog.data, prog.item;
```

You have two columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`:  `prog.item` and `prog.tempoexposicao`.  Values for these columns come from arbitrary matching rows.

This version should give consistent results:

```
SELECT prog.cod_go, prog.data, min(prog.item) as item, min(prog.tempoexposicao) as tempoexposicao
FROM tb_programacao prog JOIN
    tb_go go
    ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
where go.cod_go = '1' AND
     go.equi_func1_mat = '0735' AND
     prog.data = '2014-01-24' 
GROUP BY prog.data, prog.item;
```

Comment: well works but still the same result I want to SUM all tempoexposicao as one

Comment: Then don't do a `group by` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(temp.tempoexposicao))) AS soma_tudo,
temp.cod_go,
temp.data,
temp.item 
FROM(
SELECT
prog.cod_go,
prog.data,
prog.item,
prog.tempoexposicao
FROM tb_programacao prog
JOIN tb_go go ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
where go.cod_go = '1'
and go.equi_func1_mat = '0735'
AND prog.data = '2014-01-24'
group by  prog.data,prog.item) AS temp
```

that worked thx all!

Answer (score 0):

that works
I do the joins in subquery then I sum everythin as dinamic table
Thanks all

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(temp.tempoexposicao))) AS soma_tudo,
temp.cod_go,
temp.data,
temp.item 
FROM(
SELECT
prog.cod_go,
prog.data,
prog.item,
prog.tempoexposicao
FROM tb_programacao prog
JOIN tb_go go ON go.cod_go = prog.cod_go
where go.cod_go = '1'
and go.equi_func1_mat = '0735'
AND prog.data = '2014-01-24'
group by  prog.data,prog.item) AS temp
```